# Populating data in combobox from server in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I m getting this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined .

```
   var  infost =  Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
                    itemId:'infostore',
                    autoLoad:true,
                    fields:['Name','Address','Trade'],

                    Proxy:{
                        type:'Ajax',
                        url:'mera.json',
                        actionMethods: {
                                       read: 'POST'
                                   },
                        reader:{    
                            type : 'json',
                            root:'data',
                            totalProperty:'total',
                            record:'stu'
                        }
                    }

            });
```

Comment: Proxy shouldn't be capitalized

Comment: thanks @existdissolve for correcting but i still have two errors if u could help.

Comment: 1.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isProxy' of undefined 2.GET file:///C:/ext-4.2.1.883/First/Extjs/proxy/Ajax.js?_dc=1394789988766 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/ext-4.2.1.883/First/Extjs/mera.json?_dc=1394791669919&query=&page=1&start=0&limit=25. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I believe your `type:'Ajax'` shouldn't be capitalized either, which should eliminate your first and second problem.  The next one looks like you're trying to load data locally... is this app running on a server?

Comment: Like incutonez pointed out, you'll need to run this code on a webserver where the originating request domain is the same as the requested resource domain. Also, be very careful with case in JavaScript...typos like the 'P'roxy and 'A'jax errors will create a world of hurt if you're not paying attention. I would review the naming/capitalization guidelines here (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#/guide/class_system) so that you can know what to expect from how Ext JS handles class names, variables, etc.

Comment: @incutonez it's not runing on sever but since i m trying to populate data through ajax call i m having no idea about the error.i m new to Extjs 4 so typos don't surprise me because i don't believe in copy paste of code . Thans for advice. It would be a great help if u figure out this error so that i could learn further.

Comment: @existdissovle both json file and html are in the same folder.what i guess u mean by keeping in same domain.

Comment: @Wadhawan994: I don't believe Ext JS supports loading a local file (through the file protocol), so in order for your Ajax call to succeed, you need to be hosting your application on a server.  I recommend [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/Main), as it's very lightweight and easy to set up.

Comment: @incutonez i have IIS enabled in my machine and i think ajax call will be handled by that but i m not sure.

Comment: @incutonez  Can anyone help me knowing how to add JSON MIME type to IIS which i guess will resolve this error.

Comment: @Wadhawan994 [from Google search](http://www.uipress.com/add-json-handler-support-in-iis-7/#.UyXsGIUXfdY) "add json mime iis."